# Как закрасить круг?

Tags: java, android

Рисую круг самым примитивным способом:

```
canvas.drawCircle(0, 0, 100, paint);
```

Как залить его например красным цветом?

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так:

```
 paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
 paint.setColor(Color.RED);
```

...

```
canvas.drawCircle(0, 0, 100, paint);
```